# Is there a way to tell when a python file is loaded using PYTHONSTARTUP vs. being run as a script?

Tags: python

All,
  I recently discovered the PYTHONSTARTUP environment variable, and am looking forward to setting up several of my utility functions to automatically load into my interpreter.  However, one thing I'd like to be able to do is use the same script to setup the environment variable itself.

My issue is determining when the file is run as a script.  My thought was to use the `if __name__ == "__main__":` trick to determine when the file was run as a script, but testing showed that when the file is loaded via PYTHONSTARTUP the name shows as `"__main__"`.

Does anyone know of a way to identify when a file is run as a script vs. when it is loaded via PYTHONSTARTUP?

Comment: `PYTHONSTARTUP` just modifies `sys.path` variable, it doesn't modify the files loaded.

Comment: @Ismail: No, it actually runs the file specified.

Comment: Right, and I was thinking about _PYTHONPATH_ instead, oooops :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a better solution:

```
if sys.argv[0] == __file__:
    print "It works!"
```

Basically, because the name of the file is always the first argument in argv[] we just check if `argv[0]` is the same as the `__file__`, which is only true when the file was opened as a script.

Answer (score 3):

You could check if the PYTHONSTARTUP environment variable is set to the current filename (via `__file__`).

```
 import os
 if os.environ.get('PYTHONSTARTUP') == __file__:
     print "Used as startup!"
```

Worked fine for me.

Comment: Thanks, that works for what I need.  I guess I was just looking for something cleaner.  That statement will be True even when run as a script, as long as the PYTHONSTARTUP environment variable points to the current file.

Comment: Ah, you are right, it will, so it doesn't actually check if it's run under startup, it only checks if it is already set up or not.